# VS 2015 Code Coverage Analysis never completes

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing

I'm trying to run a Code Coverage analysis on our solution but the tests never complete (no matter how many I select).  I can run the Unit Tests normally and they complete fine, but whenever I run Code Coverage it just "hangs" or goes into some kind of infinite loop.

I enabled logging for vstestexecute and compared the logs.  All the "initialization" steps looks the same, but at the point where the successful test log says "starting test execution" the code coverage one simply stops.  I need to manually end the task on vstestexecute and if I go looking I can find an empty or corrupt .coverage file that was created.

This project has existed since Framework 1.1 on VS 2003, and been migrated up to Framework 4.7 on VS 2015 now, so that migration path may have something to do with it.

Does anyone have any tips on other diagnostic tools I can use to try to determine what is going wrong?